# Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([T.Type], from: Data)

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

I'm currently trying to make a parser which will take a json respons that holds an array of dictionaries. I've already got it working for a json response which just holds a dictionary in the following way

```
func decodeResult<T: Decodable>(model: T.Type, result: NSDictionary) -> (model: T?, error: Error?) {
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result, options: .prettyPrinted)
            let modelObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(model.self, from: jsonData)
            return (modelObject, nil)
        } catch let error {
            return (nil, error)
        }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing basically but for an array result. So far I've created this

```
func decodeResult<T: Decodable>(model: T.Type, result: NSArray) -> (model: [T]?, error: Error?) {
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result, options: .prettyPrinted)
            let modelObject = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: jsonData)
            return (modelObject as? [T], nil)
        } catch let error {
            return (nil, error)
        }
    }
```

However it gives me an error on the `JSONDecoder` where it's saying that it `cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([T.Type], from:Data)'` Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and what I'm forgetting here that causes this error?

If I would do this without the generic type but just use my `Chat` model (for example) it would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised what I forgot to change in my code and why it wasn't working, so I figured I would share the solution here for anyone that runs into the same problem.

I forgot to make the `model` input of the type `[T]` which is why it couldn't decode the given model. So this makes the entire working code look like this

```
func decodeResult<T: Decodable>(model: [T].Type, result: NSArray) -> (model: [T]?, error: Error?) {
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result, options: .prettyPrinted)
            let modelObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(model.self, from: jsonData)
            return (modelObject, nil)
        } catch let error {
            return (nil, error)
        }
    }
```